# contractible fiber implies spaces have same cohomologies

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a fiber bundle with fiber $F$ that is contractible.

Clearly $\pi_n(X)\cong \pi_n(Y)$ for all $n$. But why does it follows that $H^{*}(X)\cong H^{*}(Y)$?

Is it because the iso $\pi_n(X)\cong \pi_n(Y)$ is induced by a map?

Comment: Yes in the setting of CW complexes, see answers to duplicates to your previous question. Probably the same in general.

Comment: @MoisheKohan what about things that are not CW complexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem 7.6.25 (page 402) in

*Spanier, Edwin H.*, Algebraic topology. (1st corr. Springer ed. of the orig. publ. by McGraw- Hill, 1966), New York - Heidelberg - Berlin: Springer-Verlag. XIV, 528 p. (1982). [ZBL0477.55001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0477.55001).

states that a weak homotopy equivalence $X\to Y$ of topological spaces induces isomorphisms of homology groups $H_\cdot(X)\to H_\cdot(Y)$ (alternatively, see Whitehead's Theorem 7.5.9, page 399). By the UCT we will obtain the same for cohomology groups.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you please tell me the page number? My edition of the book ends at page 528.

Comment: @MathematicallyInterested: Done. I think we are using the same  edition from 1981.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I upvoted and liked your answer!